# Как увеличить динамически подгружаемые изображения?

Tags: html, jquery, css, изображения

Всем привет! у меня на сайте картинки подгружаются динамически, например так:

```
<? u_img(2801); ?>
```

все они находятся в общем классе gallery. Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении/клике на изображение оно увеличивалось до оригинального размера? 
Картинки могут быть разного размера. Как можно это сделать не добавляя дивов с классами или ссылок в структуру документа?

```js
$(".gallery img").fancybox();
```

```css
.gallery img {
 max-width:284px;
 max-height:333px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала получи реальные размеры изображений

```
  var ImgSizes ={},
  getImgSize = function(i,e){

        var img = new Image();     
        img.onload = function() {ImgSizes[i] ={width : this.width, height : this.height}; }     
        img.src = e.src;
    };
  $('.gallery img').each(getImgSize);
```

Таким образом, ты получаешь массив ImgSizes с реальными размерами изображений
(вместа индекса i можно использовать id или какой-либо другой удобный параметр). Дальше, при клике по картинке ты получаешь ее index ( `var i = $(this).index();` )  (либо тот параметр, который ты задал вместо индекса), и получаешь еее реальные параметры из массива ImgSizes[i], которые, в свою очередь, уже можешь применять посредством ф-ций `width()`, `height()` либо `css()`, либо - `animated()` - как угодно. Грубо говоря:

```
$(document).on('click','img', function(){
    var i = $(this).index();
    $(this).width(ImgSizes[i].width);
    $(this).height(ImgSizes[i].height);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Изначально задаете строгие размеры картинкам, например

```
.gallery img{width: 50px;}
```

Затем пишете js код, типа такого:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.gallery img').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('expanded');
    });
</script>
```

Добавляете еще один класс в css

```
.gallery .expanded{width: auto;}
```

Радуетесь

Comment: Спасибо, но строгие размеры картинки не пойдут  - когда изображение подгоняется, то выглядит не айс..
решил пойти другим способом через использование библиотеки fancybox(), по проблемка в том, что исходное изображение после срабатывания исчезает - код привел вверху